# how to use pandas to subtract rows of a column based upon data by group?

Tags: python, pandas, date, pandas-groupby, subtraction

I'm trying to compute the difference between rows of a column based upon the first and last date, by group.
for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':["a","a","a","b","b","b"],
                   'start_yr':[2010,2013,2020,2009,2005,2019],
                   'amt':[10,40,30,50,60,100]})
```

should return

```
a 20   (30-10)
b 40   (100 - 60)
```

I've tried stuff like this, but i'm missing something for sure.

```
#df['diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['start_yr','amt'].transform(lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()))
df['diff'] = dThe f.groupby('ID')['start_yr'].transform(lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try two steps:

```
s = df.sort_values(['ID','start_yr']).groupby(['ID'])['amt'].agg(['first','last'])
output = s['last'] - s['first']
```

Output:

```
ID
a    20
b    40
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

First sorting both columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then subtract last with first value in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = (df.sort_values(['ID','start_yr'])
         .groupby('ID')['amt']
         .agg(lambda x: (x.iat[-1]-x.iat[0]))
         .reset_index())
```

Or subtract values with aggregate [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID','start_yr'])
g = df.groupby('ID')['amt']

df1 = g.last().sub(g.first()).reset_index()
```

Or for first and last values is possible use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID','start_yr'])

df1 = (df.drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last').set_index('ID')['amt']
         .sub(df.drop_duplicates('ID').set_index('ID')['amt'])
         .reset_index())
```

---

```
print (df1)
  ID  amt
0  a   20
1  b   40
```

EDIT: Here is idea without sorting first by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html)
[`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for values by index (here `amt`) by minimal and maximal of `start_yr`:

```
g = df.set_index('amt').groupby('ID')['start_yr']

s = g.idxmax().sub(g.idxmin()).reset_index()
print (s)
  ID  start_yr
0  a        20
1  b        40
```

Comment: this is perfect thx.   so there is no way to use the date explicitly to refer to the other column.  sorting  first is still efficient? notably, i'm using. an actual date field. not an int as a date. i should have added that.

Comment: @nerdlyfe - If dates are datetimes, sorting working perfectly.

Comment: @nerdlyfe - Interesting question about performance. I think depends of data, also you get me idea for soluton without sorting, added to answer. Thank you.